# java byte array comparison for two dto using Arrays.equals

Tags: java, arrays

I have two DTO need to be compared using (Arrays.equals), they are never be equals . Data in both DTO are equals as I review each attribute, some times its length equals , but Arrays.equals return false, I try to use Arrays.deepEquals the same problem exist but in some fields . I found some point when I debug :

1- hashcode method not the same in both DTO.
2- problems in attributes from String type.

my question is how can I test and detect which attributes are different.

Here is my code snap :

```
    Boolean isEqual = false;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oStream;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oStream2;

    try {
        oStream = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
        oStream.writeObject(obj1);
        byte[] obj1ByteArray = bStream.toByteArray();

        oStream2 = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream2);
        oStream2.writeObject(obj2);
        byte[] obj2ByteArray = bStream2.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("Obj1>>" + obj1ByteArray.length);
        System.out.println("Obj2>>" + obj2ByteArray.length);
        isEqual = Arrays.equals(obj1ByteArray, obj2ByteArray);

        oStream.close();
        oStream2.close();
```

---

data snap :

```
    Length
Obj1>>709
Obj2>>709
------------------------------------------------
Object 1
com.beshara.hr.core.interfaces.web.job.shared.structure.dto.JobDTO@1ab5140
59
test_job_5555555
-100
59
1
وظيفة تجريبية 6
وظيفة تجريبية 6أخري
10
10
10.0
وظيفة تجريبية الغرض من الوظيفة 6

--------------------------------
Object 2
com.beshara.hr.core.interfaces.web.job.shared.structure.dto.JobDTO@4cfc52
59
test_job_5555555
0
59
1
وظيفة تجريبية 6
وظيفة تجريبية 6أخري
10
10
10.0
وظيفة تجريبية الغرض من الوظيفة 6
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your two _JobDTO_ objects: _obj1_ and _obj2_ are _not equal_ to one another based on the output you provided, because _they contain different data_. If you want anymore help with this please post your _JobDTO_ class's _hashCode_ and _equals_ implementation. Not knowing what can kind of properties/attributes these _JobDTOs_ have is kind of hard to help anymore than the help I've already (tried) to provide.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [`Arrays.equals(byte[],byte[])` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29):

> Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. In other words, **two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order**.

So, you won't be able two compare your byte arrays successfully if you expect them to contain *some* differences.

If you don't have (or don't want to have) control over how your objects are getting serialized, then you can probably use some sort of `Comparator<byte[]>`.

```
public final class MyComparator implements Comparator<byte[]> {

  private static final int ATTR_START = 0;
  private static final int ATTR_END = 7;

  @Override
  public int compare(byte[] left, byte[] right) {
    if (left.length != right.length)
      return left.length - right.length;

    byte[] leftAttr = Arrays.copyOfRange(left, ATTR_START, ATTR_END);
    byte[] rightAttr = Arrays.copyOfRange(left, ATTR_START, ATTR_END);

    return Arrays.equals(leftAttr, rightAttr) ? 0 : -1;
  }
}
```

I realize that this is a bit dodgy, so here is another take on the problem.

```
public final class MyByteArrayOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream {

  private static final int ATTR_START = 0;
  private static final int ATTR_END = 7;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    // this can be implemented based on *your* attribute/attributes
    // and its/their location in the buffer too, like in equals just below
    return Arrays.hashCode(buf);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    boolean equals = false;
    if (object instanceof MyByteArrayOutputStream) {
      MyByteArrayOutputStream other = (MyByteArrayOutputStream) object;
      byte[] thisAttr = Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, ATTR_START, ATTR_END);
      byte[] otherAttr = Arrays.copyOfRange(other.buf, ATTR_START, ATTR_END);

      if (Arrays.equals(thisAttr, otherAttr)) {
        byte[] thisRest = Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, ATTR_END, buf.length);
        byte[] otherRest = Arrays.copyOfRange(other.buf, ATTR_END, buf.length);

        equals = Arrays.equals(thisRest, otherRest);
      }
    }
    return equals;
  }
}
```

Subclass `ByteArrayOutputStream` and implement your custom equals logic.

Comment: " two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order." what they mean by "same elements in the same order." did they mean DATA if yes I use the same values for both DTOs

Comment: @SherifOmar It means that if you have two byte arrays, _a_ and _b_, then _Arrays.equals(a, b)_ will return _true_ only iff: a.length == b.length _and_ a[i] == b[i] where _i = 0, 1, .. , a.length - 1_. That is, if the two arrays contains the same byte values at their every indices.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks but not a sollution:

- Contrary to the title of your question not `Arrays.equals` is your problem but the output of `ObjectOutputStream`. And even that might not be true - it might be an Unicode encoding problem (see below).
- Please provides a [short, self contained and correct example](http://sscce.org/). Your code misses the real input data. This is adds up with the next point:
- Most readers of StackOverflow can't do anything the occasionally special character of spanish, france, german ... scripts. Let alone complete arabic words. This decimates the number of people who want to think about your problem considerably.

Finally something to the problem itself: Two different Unicode strings can be displayed in the same way due to the way Unicode allows combinations of characters. So a general advice is: Boil down your problem as far as possible.

- Compare each string pair in you DTOs by with `String.equals`.
- Each pair which returns `false` but is displayed in the same way must be examined further: Feed them to `java.text.Normailzer` using both `NFC` and `NFKC` and compare the results again.
- If results do compare now, you have Unicode encoding problems. Write up your results, prepare a [new exampls](http://sscce.org/) and dig this site with the new search phrases.

If this procedure does not work to solve your problem or to narrow downs your problem, then nevertheless provide the results from your examination by editing your question.

Oh, I nearly forgot: You stated

> I have two DTO need to be compared using ...

You should think about what you really want to achieve and *then* decide *how* to do that. If you want to compare bytes, use the `Arrays.equals`. If you want to compare DTOs, then build your own compare method by comparing each field in the DTOs doing any fancy "normalization" here. A tool to help you with that might be Apache [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html).

Comment: Thank you for your advice , Actually I use the solution of comparing these DTOs (that's does not mean that I approve , I suggest to use compare DTO instead ) , only my screen has this behavior, so I try to figure out where is the problem or even how to debug to find out the problem, you notice that it may be (ObjectOutputStream or Unicode), I try to compare by attribute's value and it works well ,but this solution refuses , I must use byte array comparsion.